# Is the libcurl example httpcustomheader.c buggy (showing bad practice) or am I missing something?

Tags: c++, c, libcurl

The libcurl examples contains an [example for custom HTTP headers](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/httpcustomheader.html).

The example makes use of *curl_slist_append* like this:

```
struct curl_slist *chunk = NULL;

/* Remove a header curl would otherwise add by itself */ 
chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Accept:");

/* Add a custom header */ 
chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Another: yes");

/* Modify a header curl otherwise adds differently */ 
chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Host: example.com");

/* Add a header with "blank" contents to the right of the colon. Note that
   we're then using a semicolon in the string we pass to curl! */ 
chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "X-silly-header;");
```

According to the [documentation of curl_slist_append](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_slist_append.html) a null pointer will be returned if something goes wrong:

> RETURN VALUE
>
> A null pointer is returned if anything went wrong, otherwise the new
>   list pointer is returned.

**Question:**

When for example the call

```
chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Another: yes");
```

fails, won't the original list, that chunk previously pointed to, be lost? And as a consequence: won't this leak memory?
Or is there some magic that I am missing and that is not mentioned in the *curl_slist_append* documentation?

To make matters worse: won't the next call to *curl_slist_append* possibly create a new list (unlikely as we are probably out of memory already, but possible)?

Comment: "These files are intended as examples only. In the interest of simplicity and clarity, they might not include proper error handling and might produce compiler warnings on some platforms. Real-world applications should pay more attention to these issues." quoted from http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suspicions seem entirely correct. The source for `curl_slist_append` can be viewed [here](https://github.com/bagder/curl/blob/master/lib/slist.c#L87).